Stretched Object
I'm sort of new to blender 4.1, and I have recently imported a model like a few weeks ago, and yesterday I noticed that one part was stretched, and a few more options with it (here Origin to Geometry) doesn't work. Can someone help please ?
The file

Hello, it's probably because the rigging is not correct, could you please share your file?

Of course, here's the file (actually I just copied the hand and the armature from the original project into a new one) in the edit just up there

Not even the hand ?

Normally you can only see the hand and the entire armature, that's what I meant to do

oops ok sorry for my mistake

Put the Armature modifier on top, activate its On Cage and Edit Mode options in order to be able to select the dyfunctional vertex and remove this vertex from the vertex group called Bone.018:


Omg it worked thank you! Have a great day :3 !

@LilianRilos If this helped you fix your problem, you should accept it. There should be a gray check mark next to this answer.
